# How to use MATLAB fread to read a txt file?

Tags: c, matlab, file-io

I try to use fread to read a text file

My code is only 2 lines

```
fid = fopen('1.txt', 'r');
c = fread(fid,'double', skipvalue);
```

I have tested different format like double, float32, float64 and different skipvalue from 0 to 8, but none of the combination work.

The data is recorded by a c program code
fprintf(file,"%f \n",sample[i]);

sample data (each row has one data only )

```
-0.992224 
0.932078 
-0.474954 
-0.659479 
-0.994677 
-0.380766 
-0.643983 
0.425023
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) function or [`fscanf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html).

`fread` is the counterpart to `fwrite`, not `fprintf`.

`fscanf` is the counterpart to `fprintf`.

If you absolutely must use `fread`, you'd read a string (character array) and then use `sscanf` to extract the numeric data from it.

Comment: @Ben -> Is there anyway to control the number of rows you read, while reading it as string?  Your suggestion was great but since my .txt file is huge, I wanted to read 'N' rows at a time (don't want to use textscan!).  Thanks...

Comment: @Maddy: This question is about reading numeric data, why the sudden concern about string?  You can tell `fscanf` how many rows to read, and MatLab will remember where you are in the file (as long as you don't close it), you can use `fscanf` with the same file handle later to continue reading where you left off.

Comment: @Ben --> I am using your suggestion to read, say 5million rows X 7 Cols of data using *char and then I convert them back to double using sscanf.  However, if my text file instead has 20million rows, I would have to read it using SomeRowCount.  I have tried fscanf which was actually slower than textscan in my case! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543281/read-a-txt-file-fscanf-vs-fread-vs-textscan) Your suggestion is by far the best.  If only I could somehow control the NumbrOfRows as using `*char` treats every character as row number.  Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Maddy: You've already been given a link to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440592/fastest-matlab-file-reading), it's the best explanation I know of covering your problem.