# Parsing/Reading file from text file with specific format in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a file that has the following structure

```
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400
```

I would parse that file into two lists.

List1 would contain `[1,2,3,4]`

List2 would contain `[100,200,300,400]`

I have tried looking around but I am having trouble with the parameters to functions such as `textread` and `fscanf`. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Relevant long-winded discussion and sample code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9441839/931379

Comment: Voting to close, duplicate of [Fastest Matlab file reading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440592/fastest-matlab-file-reading) as Pursuit indicated.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
fid = fopen( filename, 'r' );
[m n] = fscanf(fid, '%d %d\n');
fclose( fid );
list1 = m(1:2:end);
list2 = m(2:2:end);
```