# Manipulating large csv files with Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, memory

I am trying to work with a large set of numerical data stored in a csv file. Is so big that I cannot store in a single variable, as Matlab does not have enough memory.

I was wondering if there is some way to manipulate large csv files in matlab similar as if they were variables, i.e. I want to sort it, delete some rows, find the column and row of some values, etc.

If that is not possible, what programming language do you recommend to do that, considering that the data is stored in a matrix form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055958/massive-csv-file-into-matlab

Comment: bogeyc, the link you are referring is about converting csv files with characters to Matlab, what I am looking for is to ways to manipulate, with Matlab, csv files. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the csv file into a database. E.g. sqlite - https://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles 
Take one of the sqlite Toolboxes for Matlab, e.g. http://go-sqlite.osuv.de/doc/ 
You should be able to select single rows and columns due sql language and import to matlab. Or use sqlite functions (for sort -> order by etc.)...

Another option is to access csv files directly like it is a sql database with q. See https://github.com/harelba/q