# Parsing a CSV file in matlab efficiently

Tags: matlab, csv

I am working with a CSV file that contains information in the following format:

```
      col1      col2          col3
row1  id1  , text1 (year1) , a|b|c
row2  id2  , text2 (year2) , a|b|c|d|e
row3  id3  , text3 (year3) , a|b
 ...
```

The number of rows in the CSV is very large. The years are embedded in col2 in parentheses. Also, as can be seen col3 can have variate number of elements.

I would like to read the CSV file EFFICIENTLY and end up for each item (id) with an array as follows:

**For 'item' with id#_i :**

```
A = [id_i,text_i,year_i,101010001]
```

where if all possible features in col3 are [a,b,c,d,....,z], the binary vector shows its presence or absence.

I am interested in efficient implementation of this in MATLAB. Ideas are more than welcome. Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Massive CSV file into Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055958/massive-csv-file-into-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use T `= readtable(filename)`. This has the option for 'ReadVariableNames' which takes first row as header and 'ReadRowNames' that will take first column as row variable.

Comment: Thanks. readtable is pretty interesting and fast. When I apply, T=readtable(filename) and then T.col3 I can have all the list of features ('a', 'b' , 'c' ...) for each row.  Given a cell containing a string in each row, I want to a particular type of string. For example, suppose I want to find any row that contains string 'a' like 'a' , or 'a|' or '|a' or '|a|'. Ideas are more than welcome (eg. strcmp, strfind, regexp ....)

Comment: ok, I think regexp is effcient for handling seaching this type of patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add what I have found to be one of the fastest ways of reading a CSV file:

> [`importdata()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)

This will allow you to read numeric and non-numeric data, but it assumes there is some number of header lines. You can either input the number of header lines as an input argument to `importdata()` or you can let it try on its own...to which it didn't work for my use in the past.
This was much faster than `xlsread()` for me, where it took 1/6th the time to read something 6 times larger!

If you are reading only numeric data, you can use [`csvread()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)--which actually uses [`dlmread()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html).
Thing is, there are about 10 ways to read these files, and it is really dependent not only on your goals, but the file contents.