# Replace N lines in a txt file without using cell

Tags: matlab, file, fopen

Is there a faster way to replace the third line of file by another one without using cell ?

I've used this code but it slows my programs, especially that my txt file is composed by more than 1000 lines

```
% Read txt into cell A
    fid7 = fopen([handles.filenameproba],'r');
    i = 1;
    tline = fgetl(fid7);
    A{i} = tline;
    while ischar(tline)
        i = i+1;
        tline = fgetl(fid7);
        A{i} = tline;
    end
    fclose(fid7);
    % Change cell A
    newval =...

    A{3} = sprintf('StartExperiment:%s',num2str(newval);
    % Write cell A into txt
    fid7 = fopen([handles.filenameproba], 'w');
    for i = 1:numel(A)
        if A{i+1} == -1
            fprintf(fid7,'%s', A{i});
            break
        else
            fprintf(fid7,'%s\n', A{i});
        end
    end
  fclose(fid7);
```

Thanks !

Comment: I think reading the file using textscan with the newline being the delimiter would be a lot faster than fgetl 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440592/fastest-matlab-file-reading
you could also consider doing that with python should be fairly easy

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your primary concern, try this **[`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)** approach to see if it's any faster -

```
f=importdata(handles.filenameproba,'')
f(3)={sprintf('StartExperiment:%s',num2str(newval))}

%%// Save the modified text file
fid1 = fopen(handles.filenameproba,'w');
for k = 1:numel(f)
    fprintf(fid1,'%s\n',f{k});
end
fclose(fid1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells are not your problem. Your problem is reading and writing one line at a time. Additionally, you are re-sizing your cell array at every iteration.

For the following problem, I created a test file with 10000 lines in it.

```
fileId = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
for i = 1:10000
    fprintf(fileId, 'This is the %dth line.\n', i);
end
fclose(fileId);
```

I'm calling your method `ranellMethod`.

```
>> timeit(@ranellMethod)

ans =

    0.5160
```

A better way to do it is to limit the number of read/write operations you have to do. Assuming your file is small enough, you can read the entire contents into memory at once. Perform your operations, and write everything at once.

```
function entireFileMethod()
    fileName = 'test.txt';
    fileId = fopen(fileName, 'r');
    try
        text = fread(fileId, '*char')'; %'
    catch Me
        fclose(fileId);
        Me.rethrow();
    end
    fclose(fileId);
    newLineInds = find(text == char(10));
    newLine = sprintf('This is the new line. %1.*f', randi(10), rand);
    newText = [text(1:newLineInds(2)), newLine, text(newLineInds(3):end)];
    fileId = fopen(fileName, 'w');
    try
        fprintf(fileId, '%s', newText);
    catch Me
        fclose(fileId);
        Me.rethrow();
    end
    fclose(fileId);
end
```

This function has one read operation, and one write operation:

```
>> timeit(@entireFileMethod)

ans =

    0.0043
```

See [Fastest Matlab file reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440592/fastest-matlab-file-reading) for more detailed information about file IO in MATLAB