# Matlab - dlmread or textscan - which is faster

Tags: matlab, file-read

I am having time-trouble reading my ".csv" file into Matlab. Using the following part from this forum i found out the number of rows is roughly 12 Million, the number of columns is 7.

```
function count = countLines(fname)
fh = fopen(fname, 'rt');
assert(fh ~= -1, 'Could not read: %s', fname);
x = onCleanup(@() fclose(fh));
count = 0;
while ~feof(fh)
count = count + sum( fread( fh, 16384, 'char' ) == char(10) );
end
end
```

I tried the dlmread command to read it into Matlab which takes about 120 seconds:

```
tic
fname='test1_csv0.csv';
N1=countLines(fname)-1; 
N2=6;
blockmodel=dlmread('test1_csv0.csv',',',[1 0 N1 N2]);
toc
```

I found this post on fast Matlab reading

[Fastest Matlab file reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440592/fastest-matlab-file-reading)

But to be honest, as I am not a programmer, I do not know how to adapt the code to my problem and which would be the fastest option. I would like to keep the solution in Matlab, as this is the only programming-language I slightly understand. 
I would appreciate any help to get Matlab to read my matrix faster, do you have any experience whether "textscan" might work better then "dlmread" ?

Comment: `dlmread` is basically a wrapper for `textscan`. I therefore would not be surprised if you can make `textscan` work faster, since you can omit a lot of the checks performed by `dlmread`, provided you know your data beforehand. For csv files there's `csvread` as well (which also is a wrapper for `textscan`)

Comment: could you help me set up a short script for textscan ? ... i am not really sure how to use it ( the mathworks explanation is a bit confusing for me :/ )

Comment: `fileID = fopen('datafile.csv');
C = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f');
fclose(fileID); out = cell2mat(C);` should do the trick. You might as well use `csvread`, as that's written especially for CSVs and actually returns a matrix, so you don't have to manually convert it using `cell2mat`

Comment: trying to run your script i just get the following error : Error in textscan (line 3)
C = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f'); any ideas on that ?